# Is there a simple way to create a hyperlink/javascript-action on a node double-click in vis.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclicklistener, vis.js

Defining nodes in vis.js, http://visjs.org/network_examples.html , looks like this:

```
var nodes = [
{id: 1, label: 'Node1'},
{id: 2, label: 'Node2'},
{id: 3, label: 'Node3'},
{id: 4, label: 'Node4'}
];
```

What I'm trying to find out is, can you create a node double-click (or other event/click type) action, something like so:

```
var nodes = [
{id: 1, label: 'Node1', double-click: 'Arbitrary_OnClick_Function()'},
{id: 2, label: 'Node2', double-click: 'document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="Node 2 was clicked"'},
{id: 3, label: 'Node3', double-click: 'https://www.google.com;target="_blank"'},
{id: 4, label: 'Node4', double-click: '#SomePageSection'}
];
```

Perhaps there's a way to do this combining with angular.js (github.com/edgaraafelix/angular-visgraph) or non-simply through vis.js method `on(event,callback)` (`http//visjs.org/docs/network.html#Methods` and http://visjs.org/docs/network.html#Events).

Comment: Can you maybe accept the answer to mark the question as resolved? This will help other users as well.

Answer (score 6):

So from that same doc that you have the nodes example from, you eventually create a network e.g.

```
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

(the data object contains the nodes and edges)

then you can put an event listener on the network, and you know which node you clicked on from the properties like this

```
network.on( 'click', function(properties) {
    alert('clicked node ' + properties.nodes);
});
```

Comment: Simon, could you show how to add and retrieve a property of a node?  Properties.nodes contains a pretty substantial amount of information, and I'm not understanding how to fetch a custom property (such as link information) from the clicked node.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same need. Starting with Simon's answer I ended up with adding the following code:

```
network.on("doubleClick", function (params) {
    params.event = "[original event]";
    window.open("/myurl/?id="params.nodes[0],'_blank');
});
```

`params.nodes[0]` is the id of the node I'm using in url.

More examples available in source of [this visjs page](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/events/interactionEvents.html) (updated link as per PLG's comment).

Issues: I this works on any network object you double click. I don't know how to make it work on nodes only...

Comment: The link is dead and has been moved here: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/events/interactionEvents.html